# Is there difference between Xvfb option `-extension` and `+extension`?

Tags: firefox, xvfb

I'm facing `RANDR missing` problem with Xvfb and firefox.

Some people suggested `Xvfb :1 -extension RANDR` can solve the problem.
But I found a also `+extension` option.

In my environment(CentOS6.5), the both fails.

But I want to know at least if there is difference between `-extension` and `+extension`. I couldn't find entry about it in `man Xvfb`.

Do someone know about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Xserver(1)](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=Xserver&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+8+jessie&format=html&locale=en):

> ```
>   -extension extensionName
>        disables named extension. If an unknown extension name is specified, a list of accepted extension names is printed.
>
>   +extension extensionName
>        enables named extension. If an unknown extension name is specified, a list of accepted extension names is printed.
> ```

You should be able to get list of supported extensions from `glxinfo` or `xdpyinfo`.